# How to enable CORS in ASP.NET MVC and reactjs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors

I'm doing small ASP.NET MVC app with ReactJS. Backend provides data on localhost:3000, I can see data using direct link or postman, however frontend cannot receive it due to a CORS issue. CORS is enabled in `startup.cs`, it has added origin http://localhost:3000 however still I cannot access my API from frontend.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at `https://localhost:44386/api/user` from origin `http://localhost:3000` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I was able to reach data from frontend using different API in created in JS, but I cannot make it work in ASP.NET, I'm running out of ideas.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000") // Specify the allowed origin(s)
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Using Postman to verify that API provides data. Used different API server to check if frontend reads data correctly. Enabled CORS, configured it, added new origin pointing my frontend address.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP.NET 7 startup.cs was removed, therefore i had to add CORS in program.cs

here is code

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOriginPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader());
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors("AllowAnyOriginPolicy");

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```